# How to add Zoo Category in Smart Search page result?

Tags: smartsearch, zoo-cck, zoo

When i use smart search and type a Zoo Category name, the smart search auto complete suggest this category.
But in results page the category link was not there, only articles was inside in this category...

Any idea why the smart search results page dont show Zoo Category link?

Comment: did you add it to the zoo smart search layout?

Comment: Yes i did. But the results page dont show the category.